# Interview que to write query without using sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

A question I got on my last interview:

```
Following is the sql table data:
Column1   Column2   Column3
  1          8         9
  2          8         7
  3          9         5
  4          9         6
  5          9         2
  6          10        3
  7          8         1
  8          9         4
  9          10        8
  10         8         10
```

Asked to write a sql query to show the columns with highest value in column3 for each different value in column 2 without using sub query like following output:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
  4          9         6
  9          10        8
  10         8         10
```

I have tried using group by on column2 as :

```
SELECT column1,column2, MAX(column3) AS col3 FROM test1 GROUP BY column2
```

But it is giving following result:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
  1          8         10
  3          9         6
  6          10        8
```

Can anyone please help me to get my query correct ?

Comment: Must be MySQL or SQLite because that query is an error on any other RDBMS.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . Actually Postgres since 9.1 supports this as well, assuming that `Column1` is defined as a primary key (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY).  This is even ANSi standard behavior.

Comment: Forgot to mentioned database. It is MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks, that's interesting. That's news to me that it's ANSI behavior. I thought the [single-value rule](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-single-value-rule/) was pretty strict.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . Unfortunately, I don't know how to access the standard document on-line.  This is an optional feature and where the terminology "functionally dependent" comes from.  Here is a blog that references it (http://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2014/01/26/mysql-group-by-select-lists-and-standard-sql/).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, The final SQL spec is not free, but you can find [SQL 2003 drafts for download](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/sql-2003-drafts-for-download.html).